# Java new MongoClient() takes over 10 seconds

Tags: java, mongodb, performance

that question is really simple and pretty much everything is in the title.

When I do

```
MongoClient mc = new MongoClient();
```

My program hangs for about 10-15 seconds without any noticeable CPU or memory usage variation.

After this, calls to the database seems lightning fast as supposed. My program runs locally as my DB.

My dev laptop is pretty fast so it the issue is very unlikely to be hardware related.

It is the first time I use MongoDB with java. With PHP a DB connection was pretty much instantaneous so I guess it should be the same here!

Here is the output of my program

```
program start time : 1390057127744 // 0,000s

new mongojacktest // a small object I made for my tests

new MongoClient() // The output hangs here and if I comment this line I get errors
       // but my entire program runs in 5ms or less
 start time :1390057127745 // 0,001s 
getDB(myTestDb) 
 start time :1390057127745 // 0,001s
getCollection - testCollection 
 start time :1390057127745 // 0,001s

print db collections :
firstCollection
system.indexes

program exit time : 1390057143987 // 16,242s WTF?
```

Is there anything I am missing or this is normal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure but it might be that it's trying to resolve the hostname and maybe your DNS is slow or unreachable. To test (if you are running on a single Mongo node) mode pass it exact address of the server, i.e. `127.0.0.1`:

```
MongoClient mc = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
```

One more attempt you can do is to disable IPv6 protocol on your machine.

Comment: Already tried it, did not change anything. Anyways everything runs on a local machine and resolving "localhost" is never a problem for me. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Please try with "127.0.0.1" - this is default value anyway but maybe you are using older version that has "localhost" - just guessing.

Comment: @Johnride Adding a host and port made no difference?  In a small test on my own laptop, I found `new MongoClient()` took approx 0.5 seconds, but `new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017))` (or using "127.0.0.1") took half that time.  Can you write a small program or unit test to replicate the problem and post it here? With Java it's always difficult to tell what's really causing the delays, it could be you're getting unlucky with garbage collection, or it could be something completely unrelated.

Comment: Oddly enough I retried it this morning and it is as fast as expected. The entire program runs in under 200ms. Thanks for the suggestions even though I will probably never know what was the problem.